# Required steps to Add a Row in a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have ViewController with TableView embeded in. When this ViwController is launched i fire a NSURLConnection and grab 10 first results with the query from the server, this results include simply an image url and a text. I store everything in a mutabelArray and load the image then display all this results in my tableView and add the "load 10 more cell" cell.

Well the problem is when i try to load 10 more, the error " The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update" appears

```
[theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

i read that i have to remove cells first before adding others from the DataSource, but if i remove the first 10 cells from my array i have to go and get them back from the server when the user wants to scrol up to the previous results... it's really heavy and a little stupide -_-'... i'm sure there is a way to add simply new rows to the table view without loosing previous data.

Please if someone know a good and simple way or have sample code, it will really help, i'm stuck on it since 4 hours :/
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had once an equal problem and solved it as following:

1) Use a NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary as Datasource for your tableView instead of NSArray or NSDictionary

```
// old
// NSArray *dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object1",...,nil];

// new
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object1",...,nil];
```

2) If you catch up the the ten new results just add them to the dataArray

```
// Possibility 1:
for (Result *r in resultSet)
{
    [dataArray addObject:r]
}

// Possibility 2:
[dataArray addObjectsFromArray:resultSet];
```

3) Now reload your table:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
[indexes addIndex:0];
[indexes addIndex:1];
[self.myTable reloadSections:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Comment: well this method rocks :) but i'm wondering if it's a good thing to catch all this images in this NSMutableArray, imagine there is 100 thumbnail pics in this NsMutableArray, will it be a problem or cause memory warning ?

Comment: Dear john, Arrays are common behavior to deal with UITableViews and their datasource, since you do not to have initialize all the time temporary objects. Actually the NSArray is not the problem of memory leaks, but your objects and the amount of em stored within it. You can store up to 100 entries or even 5000 entries without a problem in an array ;)